# find a word on a website and get its page link

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to scrape a few websites and see if the word "katalog" is present there. If yes, I want to retrieve the link of all the tabs/sub pages where that word is present. Is it possible to do so?

I tried following this tutorial but the wordlist.csv I get at the end is empty even though the word catalog does exist on the website.

https://www.phooky.com/blog/find-specific-words-on-web-pages-with-scrapy/

```
        wordlist = [
            "katalog",
            "downloads",
            "download"
            ]

def find_all_substrings(string, sub):
    starts = [match.start() for match in re.finditer(re.escape(sub), string)]
    return starts

class WebsiteSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "webcrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["www.reichelt.com/"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.reichelt.com/"]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback="check_buzzwords")]

    crawl_count = 0
    words_found = 0                                 

    def check_buzzwords(self, response):

        self.__class__.crawl_count += 1

        crawl_count = self.__class__.crawl_count

        url = response.url
        contenttype = response.headers.get("content-type", "").decode('utf-8').lower()
        data = response.body.decode('utf-8')

        for word in wordlist:
                substrings = find_all_substrings(data, word)
                print("substrings", substrings)
                for pos in substrings:
                        ok = False
                        if not ok:
                                self.__class__.words_found += 1
                                print(word + ";" + url + ";")
        return Item()

    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        if getattr(response, "encoding", None) != None:
                return CrawlSpider._requests_to_follow(self, response)
        else:
                return []
```

How can I find all instances of a word on a website and obtain the link of the page where the word is founded?

Comment: you send empty item `return Item()` so you get empty file. You should at least `yield`  directory with data inside `for`-loop - like `yield {"word": word, "url": url}`.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `__class__` . And you could create `wordlist` at the beginning - even outside class. There is no need to create list again and again the same list. And you could use `import re` at the beginnnig. There is no need to import it again and again. And when all imports are at the beginning then other people can see what modules are needed to run this code.

Comment: but first you should turn off JavaScript in web browser and load your page in web browser. You will see what `scrapy` can get from page - because `scrapy` can't run JavaScript. If page uses JavaScript to add items then you will need Selenium or Splash to control web browser which can run JavaScript. See [Scrapy-Selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) and [Scrapy-Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)

Comment: this page shows me text in English and it doesn't have `katalog` but `catalog`. I have to use `https://www.reichelt.com/?LANGUAGE=PL` to get page in Polish with `katalog`

Comment: I went through scrapy selenium but I don't really get how to use it in my case. Can I add a step into my existing code such that first javascript is turned off and then we look for the words? Also, I tried using ```"https://www.reichelt.com/?LANGUAGE=PL"``` in my existing code but I dont see any print statements for the substrings. @furas

Comment: @furas does this method only check for the homepage or also all other tabs/links within that website? Also, could you help me with where/how to add ```yeild```? Havent used that before. Is it like creating a dictionary?

Comment: your main problem is `allowed_domain` - it has to be `"www.reichelt.com"` without `/`.

Comment: Other problem is that this tutorial is 3 years old (there is even link to Scrapy 1.5 but newest version is  2.5.0) and it uses some useless lines of code. It gets `contenttype` but never use it to decode `request.body` - and your page uses `iso8859-1` instead of `utf-8` (but only for original language; for `LANGUAGE=PL` it uses `utf-8`) and you could use `request.text` instead of `request.body.decode(..)`

Comment: other problem - it displays data on screen instead of use built-in method to save in `CSV` - but it needs to `yield yield {"word": word, "url": url}` - using `return Item()` it send empty values to file.

Comment: Do you mean that instead of ```return Item()```, I should use ``` yield {"word": word, "url": url}```? Or does that come somewhere before? @furas

Comment: It has to be inside `for`-loop like `print()`. I'm writing answer with all explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Main problem is wrong `allowed_domain` - it has to be without path `/`

```
    allowed_domains = ["www.reichelt.com"]
```

Other problems can be this tutorial is 3 years old (there is link to documentation for Scarpy `1.5` but newest version is `2.5.0`).

It also uses some useless lines of code.

It gets `contenttype` but never use it to `decode` `request.body`. Your url  uses `iso8859-1` for original language and `utf-8` for `?LANGUAGE=PL` - but you can simply use `request.text` and it will automatically decode it.

It also uses `ok = False` and later check it but it is totally useless.

---

Minimal working code - you can copy it to single file and run as `python script.py` without creating project.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import re

wordlist = [
    "katalog",
    "catalog",
    "downloads",
    "download",
]

def find_all_substrings(string, sub):
    return [match.start() for match in re.finditer(re.escape(sub), string)]

class WebsiteSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "webcrawler"
    
    allowed_domains = ["www.reichelt.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.reichelt.com/"]
    #start_urls = ["https://www.reichelt.com/?LANGUAGE=PL"]
    
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback="check_buzzwords")]

    #crawl_count = 0
    #words_found = 0                                 

    def check_buzzwords(self, response):
        print('[check_buzzwords] url:', response.url)
        
        #self.crawl_count += 1

        #content_type = response.headers.get("content-type", "").decode('utf-8').lower()
        #print('content_type:', content_type)
        #data = response.body.decode('utf-8')
        
        data = response.text

        for word in wordlist:
            print('[check_buzzwords] check word:', word)
            substrings = find_all_substrings(data, word)
            print('[check_buzzwords] substrings:', substrings)
            
            for pos in substrings:
                #self.words_found += 1
                # only display
                print('[check_buzzwords] word: {} | pos: {} | sub: {} | url: {}'.format(word, pos, data[pos-20:pos+20], response.url))
                # send to file
                yield {'word': word, 'pos': pos, 'sub': data[pos-20:pos+20], 'url': response.url}

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})
c.crawl(WebsiteSpider)
c.start()
```

---

**EDIT:**

I added `data[pos-20:pos+20]` to yielded data to see where is substring and sometimes it is in URL like `.../elements/adw_2018/catalog/...` or other place like `<img alt=""catalog""` - so using `regex` doesn't have to be good idea. Maybe better is to use `xpath` or `css selector` to search text only in some places or in links.

---

**EDIT:**

Version which search links with words from list. It uses `response.xpath` to search all linsk and later it check if there is word in `href` - so it doesn't need `regex`.

Problem can be that it treats link with `-downloads-` (with `s`) as link with word `download` and `downloads` so it would need more complex method to check (ie. using `regex`) to treats it only as link with word `downloads`

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

wordlist = [
    "katalog",
    "catalog",
    "downloads",
    "download",
]

class WebsiteSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "webcrawler"
    
    allowed_domains = ["www.reichelt.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.reichelt.com/"]
    
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback="check_buzzwords")]

    def check_buzzwords(self, response):
        print('[check_buzzwords] url:', response.url)
        
        links = response.xpath('//a[@href]')
        
        for word in wordlist:
            
            for link in links:
                url = link.attrib.get('href')
                if word in url:
                    print('[check_buzzwords] word: {} | url: {} | page: {}'.format(word, url, response.url))
                    # send to file
                    yield {'word': word, 'url': url, 'page': response.url}

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})
c.crawl(WebsiteSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: So, for example, these two links on the domain have a katalog https://cdn-reichelt.de/katalog/06-2021/ and https://www.reichelt.com/?ACTION=72 but none of them show up in the csv. Why would that be?

Comment: also, if I try to crawl this, https://www.eppendorf.com,in the terminal I only see links of different language pages being crawled. Doesnt it go in depth of all links? Gives me no output in the csv

Comment: `cdn-reichelt.de` and `reichelt.com` are not allowed by `allowed_domains = ["www.reichelt.com"]`. It visits only urls which start with `www.reichelt.com` and if there is `katalog` on page it adds visited url - not links to next pages. You would have to change `allowed_domains = ["www.reichelt.com", "reichelt.com", "cdn-reichelt.de"]`. OR you should search links on page, check if they have word `katalog` in URLs and add these urls to CSV, instead of url for current page.

Comment: to visit Polish pages you should start with https://www.eppendorf.com/PL-pl/ . This URL is in `<selection>` (and probably it uses JavaScript to reload page) but `LinkExtractor()` is used only to get URL in `<a>`

Comment: I added code which first get all links on page and later it check if `href` has word from list.

Comment: For the previous solution, is it possible to change allowed_domains such that the spider crawls all possible domains that are linked on that website? For eg cdn-reichelt.de and reichelt.com, without having to specificy them manually. Maybe with an aesterik?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with requests-html and rendering the page:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url = "https://www.reichelt.com/"

r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=2)

if "your_word" in r.html.text: #or r.html.html if you want it in raw html
    print([link for link in r.html.absolute_links if "your_word" in link])
```

Comment: I replaced "your word" with ""katalog" but I dont see any results in the print out. Did you get anything for this url?

Comment: I tried with both ```https://www.reichelt.com/``` and ```https://www.reichelt.com```

Comment: There is no result because the word "katalog" is not in the page. But for example if you seach for "usb" you will have all the links to usb products